# htaccess FallbackResource redirecting root domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am using FallbackResource to redirect any missing links to /user.php but it will redirect root domain ("incupe.com") too. It shouldn't redirect that! It will only stop redirecting if "incupe.com/index.php" is explicitly entered. Please help! This is my .htaccess file:

```
# Do not remove this line or mod_rewrite rules and search engine friendly URLs will stop working
RewriteBase /

# Always use https for secure connections
# Replace 'www.example.com' with your domain name
# (as it appears on your SSL certificate)
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.incupe.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Options All -Indexes
FallbackResource /user.php
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to redirect missing links to user.php, put the following into .htaccess instead of your code.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ user.php [L]

Options All -Indexes
```

If you have any virtual URLs, this won't work.